# Putting values from file separated by space into multi dimension array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm newbie and I don't know how to merge my parts of knowledge. 
I have to make Algorithm looking for the longest rising sequence of numbers. 
My file has 50 columns, every column has some random numbers separated with space.

I'm still trying to put them in Matrix or other multi dimension arrays but I don't know how.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class reading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] numbers = new double[101][101];
        int column = 0, row = 0;

        try {
            System.out.print("Enter the file name with extension : ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            File file = new File(input.nextLine());
            input = new Scanner(file);

            for (int columns = 0; columns < 101; columns++) {
                String input2 = input.nextLine();
                StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input2);
                int count = strToken.countTokens();

                for (int rows = 0; rows < count; rows++) {
                    numbers[columns][rows] = Integer.parseInt((String) strToken.nextElement());// writing values to arrays
                    System.out.println(numbers[columns][rows]);// test 
                }
            }

            input.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // here someday will be algorithm 

    }
}
```

**Sorry guys for my poor english i'm trying to tell what i want but it's a little bit hard for me. :(  I got file whit a lot of numbers and i have to found longest series of numbers from smaller to most bigger without replacing numbers **

little example from file "

45 -31 -21 -34 30 -2 12 21 -39 -46 -48 8 15 30 8 -48 29 12 11 -28 40 27 28 -45 2 50 8 28 14 47 -22 -20 27 16 43 -7 35 13 7 15 40 -42 23 -7 7 18
22 13 28 -33 -15 -46 12 -22 31 -33 39 34 -11 45 -25 -25 -50 48 31 -20 -25 -5 5
18 -36 -24 -17 10 24 21 -35 6 19 38 6 44 20 30 -49 -33 -44 9
37 -36 -18 2 -2 35 -2 45 -36 40 26 -42 -17 45 40 -31 -21 33 -4 -50 40 13 -50 11 12 37 -26 38 -31 7 30 4 32 -50 -7 -40 -12 27
17 -5 -11 41 -1 46 16 16 48 38 -49 10 1 25 39 26 -14 -50"

Comment: 50 colums or 50 rows?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Narrow in on a particular problem and explain what you want, what you've tried etc.

Comment: Do you want to read from System.in or from a file?

Comment: okay.  I'm looking for longest  series of numbers in column. Perhaps photo could bether tell what i want .
https://ibb.co/f0o22R

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is [the longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

Comment: Thank you so much !! God bless you Mr. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to read whitespace-separated values, the easiest solution is probably just to use [`Scanner.next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) or one of the other `next...` functions (other than `nextLine`, like [`Scanner.nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--), or [`Scanner.nextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) in your case).

These functions use whitespace as a delimiter, so each subsequent call will return the next piece of text that's between some whitespace, and also convert it to the appropriate type, if applicable.

```
input = new Scanner(file);

for (int rows = 0; rows < numbers.length; rows++){
   for (int columns = 0; columns < numbers[rows].length; columns++){
      numbers[rows][columns] = input.nextDouble(); 
   }
}
```

If you want each line in the file to be a row, the `rows` loop should be on the outside (consider that you want to start with row 0 and go through each column in the same way you'd start from line 0 and go through each value in that line).

---

This is not particularly robust (if there's something wrong with your data, it might still work or it might be hard to find where the problem is).

If you're looking for something more robust, I might recommend something more like:

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < numbers.length; rows++){
   String[] split = input.nextLine().split("\\s+"); // \\s+ is 1 or more whitespace characters
   if (split.length != numbers.length) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Line " + rows + " has " + split.length + " columns, but needs " + numbers.length);
   }
   for (int columns = 0; columns < numbers[rows].length; columns++){
      numbers[rows][columns] = Double.parseDouble(split[columns]);
   }
}
```

In Java 8 we can achieve the same result like this:

```
final int DESIRED_ROW_LENGTH = 101;
for (int rows = 0; rows < numbers.length; rows++){
   numbers[rows] = Arrays.stream(input.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
                       .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
   if (numbers[rows].length != DESIRED_ROW_LENGTH) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Line " + rows + " has " + numbers[rows].length + " columns, but needs " + DESIRED_ROW_LENGTH);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure if OP wants how to input into 2d array, or actually wants *I have to make Algorithm looking for the longest rising sequence of numbers* :-|

Comment: @notyou I'm not too sure about that either, but the question title seems to imply that this is more about just inputting the values.

Comment: Sure I threw an answer together if it's actually the algorithm OP wants :)

Comment: Sorry guys for my poor english i'm trying to tell what i want but it's a little bit hard for me. :(  I got file whit a lot of numbers and i have to found longest series of numbers from smaller to most bigger without replacing numbers

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide an alternative* to @Dukeling answer on the premise that you are actually looking for some sort of algorithm for the longest rising sequence of numbers:

Basically, do it directly while reading the file, and just check each position of ((column + 1) - (column) == 1) and update a field if so.

```
File file = new File("\\\\share\\file\\path\\file.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
int totalCount = 0;
int tempCount = 0;
int tempLineNumber = 1;
int totalLineNumber = 0;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] array = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(array[i + 1]) - Integer.parseInt(array[i]) == 1) {
            tempCount++;
        }
    }
    if (totalCount < tempCount) {
        totalCount = tempCount;
        totalLineNumber = tempLineNumber;
    }
    tempCount = 0;
    tempLineNumber++;
}
System.out.println("The max longest rising sequence of numbers is: "
        + totalCount + " at line " + totalLineNumber);
```

<sub>* I just threw this example together quickly, and most likely has an issue or two, such as missing edge cases etc</sub>

Comment: Or of course, use `>` instead of checking if `array[i + 1] - array[i] == 1`

Answer (score 0):

The actual algorithm happens on a one-dimensional array of integers.
So this could be done per line read from the file.

```
Path path = Paths.get(input.nextLine());
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {

    // Convert line into numbers:
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    int[] numbers = new int[words.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(words[i]);
    }

    // Find longest sequence in numbers array:
    ...
}
```

As other code here uses File and Scanner, I have given Path (newer alternative for File), and Files a utility class that has such nice methods like `readAllLines`.

---

Though you need no matrix, in general one does not use the typical math ordering, but line-by-line (by rows):

```
 for (int row = 0; row < count; rows++) {
     ... read a line
     for (int column = 0; column < 101; column++) {
         numbers[row][column] = ...
         System.out.print(numbers[row][column] + " ");
     }
     System.println();
 }
```